# Alternative to cPanel (With File Manager)

Tags: cpanel, web-hosting-control-panel

I am going to be hosting my website on my personal server. What are some good alternatives to cPanel?

I have looked at some (Webmin, etc.) and none seem to have a decent online file manager.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into CentOS Web Panel. It's free and can easily be installed on any CentOS server. It does have an easy to use file manager as well. Having used Webmin, CentOS Web Panel, Ajenti, and quite a few others, I've found this to have quite a few features without being too complicated to control.

## [CentOS Web Panel](http://centos-webpanel.com/) (free)

> Free CentOS Linux Web Hosting control panel designed for quick and easy management of (Dedicated & VPS) servers without of need to use ssh console for every little thing
>
> [image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: I have Ubuntu server, so CentOS isn't an option. What do you think of the others such as Webmin and Ajenti?

Comment: @Thunder-Chaser I've briefly used both [Vesta CP](https://vestacp.com/) and [Sentora](http://sentora.org/) and they did the job.